# eBay REST API Sandbox - How can I take a sku value?

Tags: api, rest, ebay-api, sku

I would like to using a method - createOrReplaceInventoryItem in sandbox ebay rest api. I cannot find a 'sku' value. How can I take it?

I read documentation about api I cannot find information about 'sku' value. Before asking I created policyopion per my user.

Answer (score 2):

You create the SKU yourself, so it is what ever you want to call it, if it is to update an item you have already posted, use https://api.sandbox.ebay.com/sell/inventory/v1/inventory_item?limit=2&offset=0

this will list all your inventory and will have the SKU you used when creating the inventory item.